# C# learner: What actually happens when i access an array[indexed] value vs direct value

Tags: c#, arrays, field

i like understanding how things work and i can't seem to find a simple explanation with google.

```
public class Understanding { 
    public int[] array = new[] {5, 6, 7};
    public int x = 5;
    public int y = 6;
    public int z = 7;
}
```

for example, if i access array[0] how is that done compared to just accessing x?

Comment: So ClrCORE is now open source and available on GitHub.  That source may answer your question best.  Also, this questions seems to have good information:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370231/how-do-arrays-work-internally-in-c-c

Comment: Search for beginner C tutorial - will show what happens in details... C# internal implementation of assignment for int is almost the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same as in any other language from the C-family (and almost all others, I guess): The physical memory address gets computed at runtime.
The difference to a simple local variable is that for a local variable the address is fixed whereas for array elements it gets computed through the simple formula:

```
[base address of array] + index * [size of array element]
```

Comment: Thank YOU Thomas Weller !!! Very much appreciate it when one takes the time to explain something without any buzz :)