# arrays (little a) work in java without the import statement (import java.util.Arrays), why is this?

Tags: java, arrays

Edit: Previous question was not clearly worded sorry.
I was talking about the general arrays working such as int[], String[], char[], ect.

Comment: Do you mean little-a "arrays" (i.e., arrays in general, stuff like `int[] arr = new int[10];`), or Big-A `Arrays` (i.e., stuff like `Arrays.sort(arr)`)?

Comment: Give an example of what works that you think should not. Are your talking about the basic language feature of arrays ?

Comment: Hi @KevinAnderson, yes, i am talking about the general stuff int[], char[], String[], ect...  I was unaware there was a difference, I will add an edit to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, java.util.Arrays is not imported by default.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1,2};
        int[] b = {1,3};

        System.out.println(Arrays.equals(a,b));
    }
}
```

Trying to compile this class will fail, due to Arrays being unknown. You will need to prepend the file with `import java.util.Arrays;` for it to compile.

If you're talking about arrays generally, as in how `int[]` is supported by default, that's a different question, and you'll need to clarify and reword what you mean. Simply, arrays are supported in C, the language Java is built upon.

EDIT: Further reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370231/how-do-arrays-work-internally-in-c-c)

Comment: Thanks, i think this answers my question, to clarify i was talking about arrays (little a) generally.  If I am understanding correctly now, Arrays (big A) is a class that provides additional functionality for arrays (little a) beyond the basic stuff you can do like accessing indexes.

Comment: I thought that might be so. In that case, the answer to how arrays work is my last statement. Reading up about how arrays work in C will help you get to grips with the underlying technical details about arrays. Knowing that Java is built upon C means that Java inherits this feature. Happy reading!